# Allow Weak Passwords

Tags: users, password

a client wants to use a very specific password and i'm trying to update it in the user page. i keep getting this error,

> Please choose a stronger password. Use at least 12 characters, and include numbers, symbols, and a mix of upper and lowercase letters. Do not use common words or sequences of letters or numbers.

it's showing up as Strong when entered in the field though.

Is there a way I can just disable all password strength verification?

Comment: did you try manually setting it in wp-cli?

Comment: I'd make sure the client knows where the blame will lie when they are hacked.